# How to parse xml to C# class when xmlns attribute is present?

Tags: c#, xml, console-application

been going nuts over this, my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfWorItems xmlns="http://someUrl" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/">
<WorkItem>
    <ItemID>596</ItemID>
    <ItemPressure>35.0000</ItemPressure>
    <ItemTableID>14</ItemTableID>
    <ItemVersion>AAAAAAAADGQ=</ItemVersion>
    <ItemTemperature>-196.0000</ItemTemperature>
</WorkItem>
<WorkItem>
    <ItemID>596</ItemID>
    <ItemPressure>35.0000</ItemPressure>
    <ItemTableID>14</ItemTableID>
    <ItemVersion>AAAAAAAADGQ=</ItemVersion>
    <ItemTemperature>-196.0000</ItemTemperature>
</WorkItem>
<WorkItem>
    <ItemID>596</ItemID>
    <ItemPressure>35.0000</ItemPressure>
    <ItemTableID>14</ItemTableID>
    <ItemVersion>AAAAAAAADGQ=</ItemVersion>
    <ItemTemperature>-196.0000</ItemTemperature>
</WorkItem>
    <WorkItem>
    <ItemID>596</ItemID>
    <ItemPressure>35.0000</ItemPressure>
    <ItemTableID>14</ItemTableID>
    <ItemVersion>AAAAAAAADGQ=</ItemVersion>
    <ItemTemperature>-196.0000</ItemTemperature>
</WorkItem>

</ArrayOfWorItems>
```

I want to parse this to my class:

```
[XmlRoot("ArrayOfWorItems")]
public class ArrayOfWorItems
{
    public List<WorkItem> WorkItem { get; set; }
}
```

logic:

```
    var doc = new XmlDataDocument();

    doc.Load(path);


    XmlNamespaceManager xmlNS = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

    xmlNS.AddNamespace("stupid_xmlns", @"http://someUrl");

    string contents = doc.OuterXml;

    MyXmlHandler handler = new MyXmlHandler();

    var t = handler.ParseXml<ArrayOfWorItems>(contents);
```

Parse method:

```
    public T ParseXml<T>(string  xmlStream)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlStream))
        {
            var items  = (T)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));

            return items;
        }
    }
```

Error:

> InnerException = {"http://someUrl'> was not
>   expected."}
>   Message = "There is an error in XML document (1, 23)."

Been at this for a while and cant figure it out, 
how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Root class needs to be specified with the Namespace attribute also .

```
[XmlRoot("ArrayOfWorItems", Namespace = "http://someUrl")]
```

Comment: Accepting this answer since it was correct for the question, but  in order to make all this work I have added another answer aswell. Thank you @Gowri Pranith

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with a friend I managed to get all of it to work.

@Gowri Pranith Was actuually right on the money from start but I had put in the wrong namespace and once I figured that out I had yet another issue:

I am use to parsing json objects and hence the logic is different when parsing. 
Friend of mine informed me that I can not have a list property inside of my parent class since xml does not handle this the same way as when parsing json, the correct way for this to work would be :

```
[XmlRoot("ArrayOfWorItems", Namespace = "http://someUrl")]
public class ArrayOfWorItems: List<WorkItem>
{
}
```

The parent class inherits the list and the parser renders them as children